# What does the underscore represent in Python?

Tags: python

I am kind of new to Python, so I am trying to read over existing code. I am a little confused on the syntax of this though.

For example:

```
rlist, _, _ = select.select(sockets, [], [])
```

I understand that `select.select()` takes 3 lists (and I assume `[]` just means empty list), but is the `_` used to denote a placeholder of some sort?

Comment: `_` is just a convention used for variables that get thrown away. Although be careful if you're using `gettext` as well as `_` is a common alias for `gettext`!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's just the name of a variable! Usually people use `_` for variables that are temporary or insignificant.

As other people have stated, `_` is a common alias for gettext, a translation library. You can identify when it's being used as gettext if you see it called as a function, eg. `_('Hello, world!')`.

**Protip:** In the python console it can be used to retrieve the result of the last statement.

```
>>> 3 + 4
7
>>> a = _
>>> print a
7
```

Comment: Unlike most of the other answers, this one is correct. Unlike my answer, it actually focuses on telling the OP what he wants to know. If you could get the gettext warning in there while keeping it this concise and readable, it would be twice as good as all the rest of the answers (mine included) together. :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll put the warning for gettext in there.

Comment: Well, I already upvoted, and I can't +2, but I would if I could. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's just an anonymous variable, and has no special meaning to python. Compare it with using `i` as a loop counter.

You generally use it to document that the surrounding code is going to ignore the value of that variable.

In the python interactive console, the result of the last expression is assigned to `_`, but that does not carry through in python programs.

Answer (score 2):

Despite what the other answers say, `_` *does* have a special meaning in Python. It's the last result printed at the interactive prompt.

```
>>> 2+2
4
>>> _+2
6
```

(Of course if there is no interactive prompt, e.g., because you're running a Python script from the shell, then it doesn't have a special meaning.)

Answer (score 0):

It represents an *anonymous variable*. It's used because the variable is required but the value can be ignored.

Comment: this is not always true ... although when used as a variable almost always ... it is also commonly used as the translation function for gettext

Comment: @JoranBeasley - In this context, that's what it represents.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you name a variable with a single underscore when you never need to refer to the variable again. For example, something like this:

```
for _ in range(10):
    print "hello"
```

This just prints "hello" 10 times, and we never need to refer to the loop control variable (`_` in this case).

In your example, `select.select(sockets, [], [])` returns a tuple (or list or set) from which you seemingly only need the first item, hence you the use of the underscores.